# Merge Sort Not Properly Sorting (C++)

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to implement merge sort but my code seems to be missing something. The code seems to be appending each sub-sorted array incorrectly for the final result, and in some cases, adding a copy of an element.

For example, if I run `A=[1,3,5,2,4,6]` through the function I get `A=[1,2,3,2,4,5,6]`; an extra 2 seems to be caught between `1,2,3` and `4,5,6`. Another example is `A=[4,2,9,8,11,3]`. When 'sorted' I get `A=[3,4,2,8,3,9,11]`. Why is this happening?

```
vector<int> mergeSort(vector<int> A)
{
    if(A.size()<=1)
    {
        //print(A);
        return A;
    }
    vector<int> left;
    vector<int> right;
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < A.size()/2; i++)
        left.push_back(A[i]);
    for(unsigned int i=A.size()/2; i < A.size(); i++)
        right.push_back(A[i]);
    vector<int> sortedLeft = mergeSort(left);
    vector<int> sortedRight = mergeSort(right);
    vector<int>::iterator iterL=left.begin();
    vector<int>::iterator iterR;
    vector<int> output;
    while(iterL != left.end())
    {
        iterR=right.begin();
        while(iterR != right.end())
        {
            if(*iterR < *iterL)
            {
                //cout << "Pushing back " << *iterR << endl;
                output.push_back(*iterR);
            }
            iterR++;
        }
        //cout << "Pushing back " << *iterL << endl;
        output.push_back(*iterL);
        iterL++;
    }
    iterR=right.begin();
    while(iterR != right.end())//appends left-over elements in right to output
    {
        if(find(output.begin(), output.end(), *iterR) == output.end())
        {
            //cout << "Pushing back " << *iterR << endl;        
            output.push_back(*iterR);
        }
        iterR++;
    }
    return output;
```

Below is the updated while loop:

```
while(iterL != left.end())
    {
        iterR=right.begin();
        while(iterR != right.end() && *iterR != -1)
        {
            if(*iterR < *iterL)
            {
                //cout << "Pushing back " << *iterR << endl;
                output.push_back(*iterR);
                *iterR = -1;
            }
            iterR++;
        }
        //cout << "Pushing back " << *iterL << endl;
        output.push_back(*iterL);
        iterL++;
    }
    iterR=right.begin();
    while(iterR != right.end())//appends left-over elements in right to output
    {
        if(*iterR != -1)
        {
            output.push_back(*iterR);
        }
        iterR++;
    }
```

Comment: _''forgets' about the value 6'_ Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [**How to Ask page**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main mistake is in the design of this loop:

```
while(iterL != left.end())
{
    iterR=right.begin();
    while(iterR != right.end())
    {
        if(*iterR < *iterL)
        {
            //cout << "Pushing back " << *iterR << endl;
            output.push_back(*iterR);
        }
        iterR++;
    }
    //cout << "Pushing back " << *iterL << endl;
    output.push_back(*iterL);
    iterL++;
}
```

Consider what happens if the left range is `3, 4` and the right range is `1, 2`.

- In the first iteration it will add both of the right elements to your output.
- In the second iteration it will *reset `iterR`* and so again.

You are left with an output of `1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4`.

If you manage to properly keep the state about which element of the right vector has been processed, your problem about the leftover elements will disappear by itself.

#### A few further hints:

[`::std::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) will probably work better.

You are passing vectors by value all the time.

Your code only works for `vector<int>`, which is an unnecessary restriction in C++. Templates make for sunny days.

Comment: I see. So I should be deleting appended elements, or at least not iterating over them. When I tried to delete such elements with vector.erase(iterR), it sends the iterator out of range. I thought this was because iterR was pointing to nothing, so instead I set the values I've already appended equal to -1 and made it so that my code ignores the negative values subsequently. This does seem to solve the  copy problem, but there is still a problem with the code not sorting properly. For example, if A=[4,2,9,8,11,3], then it will return [3,4,2,8,9,11]. The updated loop is in the main post.

Comment: What you have coded is a top down merge sort. You could consider a bottom up merge sort that does a one time allocation of a vector the same size as the vector to be sorted. The initial state treats a vector of size n as n runs of size 1 (use iterators or indexes to access the runs), and the merge process merges even runs with odd runs, doubling the size of runs on each pass until the  run size >= vector size. Examples of index based top down / bottom up merge sort: [wiki merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) . The wiki examples could be cleaned up to avoid the copy back steps.